# AES-256-CBC encrypted in Ruby gives padding error when decrypted in Java

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm using the following code to encrypt a piece of text:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'


aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)

ase.encrypt

aes.key = ...

encrypted_text = aes.update('text to encrypt') + ase.final

Base64.encode64(encrypted_text)
```

The problem is: when the encrypted text gets decrypted in Java, it gives the following error:

> Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher

I can set padding on encryption in Ruby, and even I did so, but the error is still the same.

Note: I don't have access to Java code. I have access to an API that is written in Java, and I need to connect my Ruby on Rails code to that.

Edit:

Encrypted text that I got by running the Ruby script: `xJG4s8/xqBJ/S+AlHu3mQ/sb6V5QYx+yDkdGdaK5wq9C7CQZa/+UPsB8C3MH\nXoLl\n`

Comment: Can you include an example of some ciphertext produced by the above code?

Comment: @LukePark Sure. I have updated my question

Comment: [AES/CBC encrypt in Java, decrypt in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6475469/608639), [AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encrypt in java decrypt in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18462243/608639), [Convert Encrypt code in java to Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28235569/608639), [Problems encoding/decoding using AES-128-CBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8330364/608639), [AES java encoding, ruby decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2506547/608639), [How to apply AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47233153/608639), etc

Comment: Try removing the newline characters from the output of the Ruby base64 encoder, or use instead `Base64.strict_encode64()`.

Comment: THe Base64 encrypted data has linefeed characters in it: `\n`, this is not a good idea foe Base64 encoding encrypted data,use an option that doews not add line seperators whrn Base64 encoding.